# Database factory in Quarkus + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, quarkus-panache

We want to build an application (REST web services) which can support multiple databases e.g. mysql and mongo DB. This application is more like a product which can be deployed in different banks, companies, etc. Application do not need to have 2 different code bases having 2 different implementations. Application has multiple layer like Controller, Service, DAO, Repository, Mapper, DaoFactory, etc..

For functionality to fetch all employees from database, application will have GET API for employees. The call will from from Controller to Service to DAO to Repo to DB and give all employees available. Depend on client's environment, client may have Mongo or MySQL, at the run time based on property (or command line parameter) the call should land on MySQL repo or Mongo Repo. We are using Quarkus JPA and hibernate for DB layer. To fetch the correct repo, we have created a factory which returns an implementation against interface (Interface pattern).

Here is a factory code

```
public class CarRepoFactory {
    public static CarInterface getInstance(String db_variant){
        if(db_variant.equals("MYSQL")){
            return new CarMysqlRepoImpl();
        }else{
            return new CarMongoRepoImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is interface against which dao layer will create an instance of repo

```
public interface CarInterface {
    void saveCarDetails(CarVO carVO);
    List<CarVO> getCarDetails();
}
```

Here is mySqlRepo

```
public class CarMysqlRepo implements PanacheRepositoryBase<CarMysqlEntity,Integer> {}
```

Here is mySqlRepoImpl

```
public class CarMysqlRepoImpl implements CarInterface {

    CarMysqlRepo carMysqlRepo = new CarMysqlRepo();

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void saveCarDetails(CarVO carVO) {
        carMysqlRepo.persist(CarMysqlEntity.builder().carName(carVO.getCarName()).model(carVO.getModel()).build());
    }

    @Override
    public List<CarVO> getCarDetails() {
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from Cars where model='KIA'").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Here are sample methods of the DAO where we want to use the Repo

```
public class CarDAO {
    public CarDAO(){
        carInterface = CarRepoFactory.getInstance(dbVariant);
    }
    
    public void saveCarDetails(CarVO carVO){
        carInterface.saveCarDetails(carVO);
    }
}
```

The problem is, in DAO, it says carInterface object shows recursive (cyclic dependency) dependency. When we try to make it @Lazy, it still shows null.

Comment: that sounds like "Entity" issue then repository, it would be easier to solve if you shared a [reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).